# Main UITableVew is visible in searchResultsTableView status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have two `UITableView`s in my app (one for regular usage and another for searching). When I use regular one the status bar is opaque but when I enter `searchResultsTableView` I can see some items from regular `UITableView`.

[image]

As you can see the `UISearchBar` is opaque so there is nothing behind it but status bar is still transculent.
I've already added `[self.tableView setHidden:YES];` in `searchDisplayController: willShowSearchResultsTableView:` but it's a very primitive solution and does not work when my regular `UITableView` is displayed at the beginning of search.

**My question is how to make status bar opaque?** Just to avoid this annoying thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two solutions to this issue. Both works for me but the second one is simpler and you don't have to do anything in code. I hope you find it useful!

---

### First solution:

You can create a custom `UIView` in code and add as a subview. If your application has one color of `UINavigationBar` or any other component and it won't change through the lifecycle you can always implement this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption:`. Otherwise, you can always add this code in proper moment but you have to remember to add this subview to proper super view. Here is the code sample:

```
UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.79 green:0.79 blue:0.81 alpha:1];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```

---

### Second solution:

There is one tiny checkbox in Xcode called **Clip Subviews** and it's super useful in that case. You can find the view which is visible under Status Bar (In my case it's `UITableView`) and clip it to subviews. I don't know how but in my case `UISearchBar` started affecting status bar so now it's opaque qith a color of `UISearchBar`.